# Making an https POST request with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I wrote a simple python script which makes an http POST request to virustotal.com and my script functions but it uses http to make a request and I want to use https.  I am using the request method from the requests library.  I am having real trouble finding the syntax to use https instead of http.  The documentation for the method doesn't make this clear to me.  Can someone post an example of how to make an https POST request with this library?  I am stuck.  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: `requests.post("https://...", ...)`? Could you give a [mre] of what you're currently trying?

Answer (score 0):

For your requests question, you designate the protocol in the url you set:

```
url = "https://virustotal.com/"
x = requests.post(url)
print(x.content)
```

My suggestion if you're trying to interact with virus total is to look at the vt-py module. https://virustotal.github.io/vt-py/